# Program works differently from IDE and from system

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, opencv

Using a simple code to open the camera:

```
// hardcoded for this time
string _pathToCam = "rtsp://192.168.2.2:554/user=admin&password=&channel=1&stream=0.sdp?real_stream--rtp-caching=100";
if (_pathToCam.length() > 1)
    vc.open(_pathToCam);
else
    vc.open(0);

if (!vc.isOpened())
{
    cerr << "Can't open stream!";
    return 1;
}
```

Using router for connect pc to cam.
When I run the program from the IDE - program is operating normally, but when I run programm from system (by clicking at exe file), program can't open the camera.
When I connect camera to pc without router - program is operating normally by running exe too.

```
SYSTEM = IDE = TRUE
IDE + ROUTER = TRUE 
SYSTEM + ROUTER = FALSE
```

**What could be the problem?**

Additional info:

- Full Code: http://pastebin.com/xCX20BLq
- OS: Windows 7 x64 Ultimate
- OpenCV: 3.1.0
- IDE: Visual Studio 2015 Community

P.S.: sorry for my english.

Comment: I bet some environment variable or folder location that differs from your IDE execution environment. See where does the code run in your IDE and where you run it when you execute the exe, compare the differences and correct it.

Comment: Is the program run as Debugging in the IDE or Release?  Some IDEs will initialize all variables in Debug mode, whereas only initialized variables in Release mode will have valid values.  Review all variables for initialization before usage.

Comment: I think that in the case of different environment variables or not initializing variables - have not always worked, instead in a single case. Of course, I will test it today, but 100% is not the case

Comment: Read full question, not only header!